# Modify Icon for parent and child in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, icons

I want to modify icons on a wordpress site.
I have a list of product categories. There are also subcategories.

[image: screencapture]

I want to put an icon for the parent categories and a different icon for the child category.
Doing this :

> .widget_product_categories ul li:before {     content: "\f7ab"; }

I changed all the icons but I don't know how to change seperately the parent from the child.

I don't know how to do it in CSS anymore. Could you help me ? Thanks for taking the time to answer.

```css
ul.product-categories {
}
.widget_archive ul, .widget_categories ul, .widget_layered_nav_filters ul, .widget_layered_nav ul, .widget_links ul, .widget_nav_menu ul, .widget_pages ul, .widget_product_categories ul, .widget_recent_comments ul, .widget_recent_entries ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.widget_archive ul, .widget_categories ul, .widget_layered_nav_filters ul, .widget_layered_nav ul, .widget_links ul, .widget_nav_menu ul, .widget_pages ul, .widget_product_categories ul, .widget_recent_comments ul, .widget_recent_entries ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.widget ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.widget_archive ul, .widget_categories ul, .widget_layered_nav_filters ul, .widget_layered_nav ul, .widget_links ul, .widget_nav_menu ul, .widget_pages ul, .widget_product_categories ul, .widget_recent_comments ul, .widget_recent_entries ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.widget ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul {
    list-style: disc;
}
ol, ul {
    margin: 0 0 1.41575em 3em;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: disc;
}
ol, ul {
    margin: 0 0 1.41575em 3em;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
.widget-area .widget {
    font-size: .875em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.widget-area .widget {
    font-size: .875em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.header-widget-region, .site-content {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.header-widget-region, .site-content {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
body, .secondary-navigation a {
    color: #0d25ad;
}
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro,HelveticaNeue-Light,Helvetica Neue Light,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif;
}
body, button, input, textarea {
    color: #43454b;
    line-height: 1.618;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-weight: 400;
}
body {
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro,HelveticaNeue-Light,Helvetica Neue Light,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif;
}
body, button, input, textarea {
    color: #43454b;
    line-height: 1.618;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-weight: 400;
}
body {
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
:root {
    --wp-admin-theme-color: #007cba;
    --wp-admin-theme-color-darker-10: #006ba1;
    --wp-admin-theme-color-darker-20: #005a87;
}
:root {
    --wp-admin-theme-color: #007cba;
    --wp-admin-theme-color-darker-10: #006ba1;
    --wp-admin-theme-color-darker-20: #005a87;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product-categories" wfd-id="31"><li class="cat-item cat-item-20 cat-parent" wfd-id="53"><a href="https://www.naturalriders.fr/categorie/le-cavalier/">Le Cavalier</a><ul class="children" wfd-id="54">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-39" wfd-id="58"><a href="https://www.naturalriders.fr/categorie/le-cavalier/accessoires/">Accessoires</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-36" wfd-id="57"><a href="https://www.naturalriders.fr/categorie/le-cavalier/bracelets/">Bracelets</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-37" wfd-id="56"><a href="https://www.naturalriders.fr/categorie/le-cavalier/ceintures/">Ceintures</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-38" wfd-id="55"><a href="https://www.naturalriders.fr/categorie/le-cavalier/tours-de-chapeaux/">Tours de chapeaux</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate them use
`.widget_product_categories ul li:before { content: "\f7ab"; }` for parent
and
`.widget_product_categories ul li ul li:before { content: ""}` for child.

Btw, your HTML code is wrong. There should be one more `</li>` and one more `</ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can show me HTML code of this categories and subcategories? We have to identification diferences between this categories and subcategories and send CSS or Javascript with create new class or something like this. :)

Comment: Hello ! thanks for taking the time to answer ! Isn't the snippet working at the bottom of my post ? I have put the css and then the html (ul li)

Comment: No problem, but i need to see more, give me source code part with all categories in the first picture